# Can any one help hover an image of an icon vertically and horizontally within a div with a border radius

Tags: html, css, image, center

I am trying to place an image at the center of each of the following four divs.I have tried placing the image as a background and it covers it but due to the border radius it doesn't look quite right. I have included a fiddle for reference.
 HTML:

```
<div id="gold" class="divSquare">1</div>
<div id="lblue" class="divSquare">2</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
<div id="redb" class="divSquare">3</div>
<div id="dblue" class="divSquare">4</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gold{
background-color:#F3B500;
border-radius: 100px 100px 5px 100px;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

#gold:hover{
opacity: 0.8;
transform: scale(1.2);
border:none;
margin:8px;
}
#lblue{
background-color:#0E43C6;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 5px;  }
#lblue:hover{
opacity: 0.8;
transform: scale(1.2);
margin:8px;}
#redb{
background-color:#7E0202;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
border-radius: 100px 5px 100px 100px; 
}
#redb:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
transform: scale(1.2);
margin:8px;}
#dblue{
background-color:#041871;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
border-radius: 5px 100px 100px 100px;
}
#dblue:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
transform: scale(1.2);
margin:8px;}
.divSquare{
width:100px; height:100px; margin:2px;float:left;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 150px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gerryboy/osaqnzoL/

Comment: sorry..didnt get your question...could you please explain it a bit more clearly..

Comment: There are no images in your fiddle...it's not really clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could center content in your divs using flexbox (if it's not a problem for your compatibility requirements):

```
.divSquare {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hameypgu/)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want place the image using css property background-image on div and OnHover of div you want to increase the size of the div and the image also.
Please let Know if my understanding is right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be using a background image unless there's an absolute requirement tha the image be content.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 3em;
}
#gold {
  background-color: #F3B500;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-25-25-2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 5px 100px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
#gold:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border: none;
}
#lblue {
  background-color: #0E43C6;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 5px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
#lblue:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
#redb {
  background-color: #7E0202;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 100px 5px 100px 100px;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
#redb:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
#dblue {
  background-color: #041871;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 5px 100px 100px 100px;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
#dblue:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.divSquare {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="gold" class="divSquare">1</div>
<div id="lblue" class="divSquare">2</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
<div id="redb" class="divSquare">3</div>
<div id="dblue" class="divSquare">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the position / margin top properties at 50% and an opposite transform: translateY of 50% for the vertical alignment.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: tranlateY(-50%);
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/osaqnzoL/5/) with some CSS enhancements.

This [one](http://jsfiddle.net/osaqnzoL/6/) is with images as background covering all the shapes. Needs tweaking, but can be achieved. don't forget to use the:

```
.divSquare{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to mask out the bleeding of the images.